# Can only connect to network printer with the only PC that uses normally an ethernet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer

Our printer is connected to the network with wi-fi. I configured it so it has the ip 192.168.1.3. All other devices are making use of DHCP.

Since this week, only my father can print or browse to the HP B110a's webserver. His PC is connected to the network with an ethernet cable.

When I plug an ethernet cable into the router and my laptop, i can't reach the webserver either. Tried to disable the anti-virus and windows-firewall, reinstall HP's printer drivers, tried the windows network and the printing troubleshooter ...

My brother also have the same problem. (didn't try to connect his laptop to the network with a cable yet, but i think it will be the same).

We use windows 10 (my brother didn't update to W10 so he still has W7)

Is there anything else that I didn't try?

Answer (score 1):

Browsing (service discovery) protocols often use multicast. Multicast is tricky to do well on Wi-Fi. Make sure your Wi-Fi security type is WPA2 Personal only (WPA2-PSK only, AES-CCMP only). Don't leave any form of original WPA or TKIP enabled. If your router lets you set the multicast rate or the basic/required rate set for your wireless network, make sure it's set to allow all rates, even rates from older/slower Wi-Fi technologies (devices at distance use these rates when needed, so disabling them does more harm than good).

Double check that all devices on your network are on the same IPv4 subnet with the same subnet mask and default gateway (make sure configs your DHCP clients get have the same subnet, subnet mask, and default gateway as the static configs you're giving to things like your printer).

If your wireless router has a "client isolation" feature, disable it.

If your wireless router has a "guest network" feature, or any kind of "multiple SSIDs / wireless networks" feature, make sure all devices are on the same wireless network (typically the main network, not the guest network).

**Edited to add:** If you manually give your printer a static IP address in the printer's settings, make sure it's not part of the DHCP server's lease pool (in most home networks, the router is the DHCP server). For example, if your DHCP pool is .2 through .200, give your printer .201. Maybe the .3 address you gave your printer was in your DHCP lease pool, and now the DHCP server has leased it to some other device, and there's an IP address conflict.